# ASP Classic wrapper for DLL

Tags: dll, com, asp-classic

I wish to use a particular API from my ASP Classic code. The API comes in the form of a DLL with .h and lib file. I have managed to use the api from my own Windows C++ application. I now wish to do the same for ASP. There is also a .NET Wrapper for this API which I haven't examined yet.

Furthermore, we will at some stage in the future migrate to ASP .NET or Python Django.

How would you recommend I wrap this API?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to wrap the DLL API that you need to use as a COM object.

The original ASP model makes use of COM to interface with native code.